# jQuery data() object to JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, serialization

I'm trying convert jQuery Data object to JSON string.

I tried:

`$.data(plant).toJSON()`

`JSON.stringify($.data(plant))`

but doesn't seems to be working. It showing undefined in firebug.(edited)

This is what I got when I log $.data(plant):

`Object { residential="Condo", location="Garden", watering="Weekly"}`

Can anyone tell me how to convert this jQuery data() object to JSON string?

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to be working", what do you mean precisely?

Comment: I'm not aware of objects having a function `.toJSON()`, but the second line should "work".

Comment: @Ionesomeday It retruns undefined in firbug

Comment: @Felix Kling when I firebug $.data(plant) and click on Object this is what i got Fruits_Vegetables "1"
 
Native_Species "1"
 
toJSON function()

Comment: You probably forgot the quotes around `plant`.

Comment: @Tom I declared plant as the javascript object(var selectedPlant = {};). It is correctly returning data, but I cannot serialize it.

Comment: @FelixKling: `.toJSON()` is used in a few browsers with explicit JSON support and the Prototype library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JSON.stringify() should work just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/gR4nQ/

Comment: Thank you for your example. I changed to use DOM element instead of JavaScript object as the data() container its working :) thank you so much.